# Prefix patterns for DTOs

Tags: design-patterns

I have some endpoints, that have their DTOs.
Nowadays, the DTO's names are becoming awful.
For example, the service: order/item/ean
Our main response file, was named: OrderItemEanResponseVo.
All subclasses received the prefix OrderItemEan either.

But, for example, we have an entity OrderItem inside of it.
Its name is: OrderItemEanOrderItemVo.

Yes, its terrible.

Do you know any pattern to name DTOs?

Comment: What other characters can you use in the names? Eg use underscores to split class names from member names? Using operation words, or really considering what ords are necesary in class names can also make a difference. Is it really and OrderItem that happens to include an EAN, or is it an OrderItemEanMapping?

Answer (score 0):

There's no single answer to this, as you probably guessed, but when it comes to naming, in particular in a nested context, I usually refer to Robert C. Martin's Clean Code Chapter 2, Don't Add Gratuitous Context:

> "In an imaginary application called "Gas Station Deluxe", it is a bad
>   idea to prefix every class with GSD. Frankly, you are working against
>   your tools. You type G and press the completion key and are rewarded
>   with a mile-long list of every class in the system."
>
> [...]
>
> The names `accountAddress` and `customerAddress` are fine names for
>   instances of the class `Address` but could be poor names for classes.
>   `Address` is a fine name for a class. If I need to differentiate between
>   MAC address, port addresses, and Web addresses, I might consider
>   `PostalAddress`, `MAC`, and `URI`.

Use meaningful context, but don't let your naming be a trail all the way to the top of your domain. That is what your namespace is for.

Consider for example, the get method of a repository, `MovieRepository`, which retrieves movies. Meaningless context would be to give it a method `GetMovie(int id)`. Instead, use `Get(int id)`. It is sufficient context, as your consumer is well aware of the context they are using this.

I think only you and your colleagues know your domain well enough to establish how much context is necessary for it to be meaningful, and not wasteful, but if it is necessary to use OrderItem as a prefix to its nested members for them to be meaningful, perhaps you need to consider if they are closely bound to your business domain, or perhaps too general?